# I'm having trouble with nesting do while and else if?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

so I'm really confused on why my code isn't working. So this is what I have so far:

```
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(prompt1);
    int value1 = keyboardInput.nextInt(), qAnswered=0; 
    String schoolMas, school;
    String answer;
    do  {
        if(qAnswered==0) {
            schoolMas = "Sooners";
            school = "Univeristy of Oklahoma";              
        } else if(qAnswered==1) {
            schoolMas = "Badgers";
            school = "University of Wisconsin";
        } else if(qAnswered==2) {
            schoolMas = "Wolverines";
            school = "University of Michigan";
        } else {
            schoolMas = "Cornhuskers";
            school = "University of Nebraska";
        } 


        if(value1 == 1) {
                System.out.println("Answer with one of: " + schoolOptions + ". ");
                System.out.println(schoolMas +"?");
                keyboardInput.next(); //two skip new comment
                answer = keyboardInput.next();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(school)) {
                score = score + 1; 
                }
                else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("I don't know")) {
                    score = score + 0; 
                }
                else {
                    score = score + -1;
                }
            qAnswered ++;
            }

        else if(value1 == 2) {
            System.out.println("Answer with one of: " + mascotOptions + ". ");
            System.out.println(school +"?");
            keyboardInput.next();
            answer = keyboardInput.next();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(schoolMas)) {
                score = score + 1;
                }
            else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("I don't know")) {
                score = score + 0;
            }
            else {
                score = score + -1;
            }
            qAnswered ++;
        }
        else if(value1 ==3) {
            break;
        }

    } while(qAnswered < 4&& value1 !=3 );
```

and when I run the program this happens:
       " In this game, I ask you four questions about mascots for US collegiate sports teams.
You get 1 point for each correct answer, 0 points if you type don't know, and you lose a point for wrong answers.

Type 1 and I'll give you the mascot and you give give the school. 
Type 2 and I'll give you the school and you give me the mascot. 
Type 3 and I'll quit.
1
Answer with one of: University of Michigan, University of Nebraska, University of Oklahoma, University of Wisconsin. 
Sooners?
university of oklahoma
Answer with one of: University of Michigan, University of Nebraska, University of Oklahoma, University of Wisconsin. 
Badgers?
university of wisconsin
Answer with one of: University of Michigan, University of Nebraska, University of Oklahoma, University of Wisconsin. 
Wolverines?
Answer with one of: University of Michigan, University of Nebraska, University of Oklahoma, University of Wisconsin. 
Cornhuskers?
"

The problem is between where it says "Wolverines" and "Answer with one of..." I can't type in the answer for the school. How can I solve this?
I tried changing the last else to else if, but when I do that I get errors.
Thank you!

Comment: Start by indenting the code correctly, to help your brain, and ours, figure out what the code does.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your first `if` statement and do some debugging going line by line.

Comment: how do I put a breakpoint in? @Voicu

Comment: Are you using an IDE (such as IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans)?

Comment: yes I'm using Eclipse @Voicu

Comment: This should help: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html. This will help you in the long run too, not just for your current issue.

Comment: When I run this code you posted, on which line(s) does it not behave like you want it to?

Comment: You might also want to look at `switch` statements to replace multiple `if else`.